# How do I add a column to the Lookup No Match Output in the SSIS Lookup Transformation?

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to clear up some of the clutter of an SSIS package I have by removing (hopefully) unnecessary transformations. I have a Lookup Transformation that matches incoming addresses by County Name and adds a column with the FIPS value of the County when matched.

I would like to add a column to the No Match Output that creates a column with the same name and type as the FIPS column, but null. I am able to add a column and name it, but when I try to assign a data type, it gives me an error as follows:

```
Error at Get Demographics [LOOKUP County [893]]: The LOOKUP County does 
not allow setting output column datatype properties.
```

If I try to save it without a datatype, then I get an error for missing data type on the column.

Any clue how I can do this without having to add a Dervied Column Transformation, or is that my only choice here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid setting things up in the output columns of transformations - it can lead to some funny behaviour and can also be a pain for someone to support in future.

If you're sending the "no match" rows out, adding a null, and then doing a Union All to bring all of the rows back together, then set the Lookup (where it says **Specify how to handle rows with no matching entries**) to **Ignore failure** instead of **Redirect rows to no match output**. You'll no longer have a No Match Output, and there's no need for a Derived Column or a Union All - [the rows with no match will simply have a null column](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/blogs/jeoc/archive/2015/02/23/18146.aspx).

And for future reference, note that if you do a Union All to bring together two flows, and one flow doesn't have some of the columns, [the rows from that flow will simply end up with nulls](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7257.ssis-union-all-transformation.aspx) - so there's no need to manually add the nulls in.

Comment: You are my hero. All this time, I thought SSIS dropped rows that were not matched when _Ignore failure_ was selected. This is infinitely cleaner and should definitely speed this package up. Thanks!

Comment: @dageniusal No problem - it's really not made very clear within SSIS, and I think this is a common mistake as a result. Why they couldn't just say "Use NULL value" or something like that I have no idea. The pattern you were using is only needed if you want to do something different with the unmatched rows. If you ever _do_ want to drop unmatched rows, just tell them to go to the no match output, then don't send them anywhere.